# Generate test parameters from json file

Tags: pytest

I'd like to get setup and verification test parameters from json file that looks something like this:

```
setup_verify_foo.json
[
{
    "test1" : {
        "setup" : {},
        "verify" : {}
    }
},
{
    "test2" : {
        "setup" : {},
        "verify" : {}
    }
}
]
```

I was thinking of having this under the same directory as the test module that looks something like:

```
/tests/foo
  test_foo.py
  setup_verify_foo.json
```

In test_foo.py, I'd like to have test parameter json objects for `test1` and `test1`.  I'm thinking something like:

```
# in test_foo.py
def test_foo(setup_verify):
  # setup for this test
  setup_verify["setup"]

  # run test
  run_data = run_my_test()

  # get verify data
  setup_verify["verify"]
```

I'm thinking that I would need to use `pytest_generate_tests(metafunc)` but not sure how to do this. This is where I need some help?  I'm thinking something like:

```
# in conftest.py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
  if "setup_verify" in metefunc.fixturenames:
    # get module path.  How do I do this?
    # get module name.  How do I do this?
    # strip _test and create json file name.
    with open(json_full_path, 'r') as f:
        obj = json.load(f)
        metafunc.parametrize("setup_verify", obj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, here's how I solved this.

Slight modification to setup_verify.json:

```
[
{
  "test_description": "This test1 ...",
  "setup" : {},
  "verify" : {}
},
{
  "test_description": "This test2 ...",
  "setup" : {},
  "verify" : {}
}
]
```

Changes to conftest.py hook `pytest_generate_tests(metafunc)`:

```
# in conftest.py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
  if "setup_verify" in metefunc.fixturenames:
    module_path = os.path.dirname(metafunc.module.__file__)
    module_name = os.path.basename(metafunc.module.__file__)
    json_name = module_name.replace('test', 'setup_verify').replace('.py', '.json')
    json_path = os.path.join(module_path, json_name)
    # open json file and parameterize it into test list
    if os.path.isfile(json_path):
      with open(json_path, 'r') as f:
        obj = json.load(f)
        metafunc.parametrize("setup_verify", obj)
      else:
        metafunc.parametrize("setup_verify", [None])
```